# Matrix Factorization and Gradient Descent

Tags: vector, gradient-descent

I am following the paper found [here](http://www2.research.att.com/~volinsky/papers/ieeecomputer.pdf) and am trying to do Batch Gradient Descent (BGD) instead of the Stochastic Gradient Descent (SGD) as described in the paper.

For SGD what I gather is you do this (pseudocode):

```
for each user's actual rating {

    1. calculate the difference between the actual rating
       and the rating calculated from the dot product
       of the two factor matrices (user vector and item vector).

    2. multiply answer from 1. by the item vector
       corresponding to that rating.

    3. alter the initial user vector by the figure
       calculated in 2. x by lambda e.g.:

            userVector = userVector + lambda x answer from 2.
}
```

`Repeat for every user`

`Do the same for every Item, except in 2. multiply by the user vector instead of the item vector`

`Go back to start and repeat until some breakpoint`

For BGD what I did was:

```
for each user {

    1. sum up all their prediction errors e.g. 
       real rating - (user vector . item vector) x item vector
    2. alter the user vector by the figure calculated in 1. x by lambda.
}
```

`Then repeat for the Items exchanging item vector in 2. for user vector`

This seems to make sense, but on further reading, I have become confused about BGD. It says that BGD must iterate throughout the entire dataset just to make 1 change. Does this mean like what I have done, the entire dataset relative to that particular user, or does it literally mean the entire dataset?

I made an implementation that goes through the entire dataset, summing every single prediction error and then using that figure to update every single user vector (**so all user vectors are updated by the same amount!**). However, it does not approach a minimum and fluctuates rapidly, even with a lambda rate of 0.002. It can go from an average error of 12'500 to 1.2, then to -539 etc. Eventually, the number approaches infinity and my program fails.

Any help on the mathematics behind this would be great.